# Exclude a data member from JSon serialization

Tags: json, docusignapi

This is with the Docusign Rest api. When I call ToJson() on an EnvelopeDefinition, it returns the correct info, but I would like it to not serialize the base64 array for when I am writing this out to a log file. I tried using the [JsonIgnore] directive, but that stopped the array from being serialized altogether. Do I need to override the Serialize method on this class or just create another method, something like ToJsonForLogging() and not serialize that array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created an extension method that will work for you. You can call this extension method in your code as follows

```
string json = envelopeDefinition.ToJsonLog(logDocumentBase64:false)
```

I am copying the DocumentBase64 into a temporary List and then using .ToJson() function to log without the documentBase64 property.

```
public static class EnvelopeDefinitionExtensions
{
    public static string ToJsonLog(this EnvelopeDefinition envDefinition, bool logDocumentBase64 = true)
    {

        if (logDocumentBase64) return envDefinition.ToJson();

        var tempDocumentBase64List = new List<string>();
        foreach(var doc in envDefinition.Documents)
        {
            tempDocumentBase64List.Add(doc.DocumentBase64);
            doc.DocumentBase64 = null;
        }
        string json = envDefinition.ToJson();

        int i =0;
        foreach(var doc in envDefinition.Documents)
        {

            doc.DocumentBase64 = tempDocumentBase64List[i];
            i++;
        }
        return json;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a champ. Thanks so much.

Comment: Oops. Forgot to do that. I do thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without working on the envelope definition that you will be sending out? We had times where substituting back the document bytearray didn't work and the placeholder was what was getting sent to Docusign. I guess the envelope definition could be cloned into another envelope definition and modify the clone.

Comment: Using your method, I created a clone method in the EnvelopeDefinition class. I clone my envelope definition and use the clone to make the new json string. Since I'm not going to put the byte arrays back, I just find them in the cloned object and substitute the placeholder there.